# Publishing vscode extension fails

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to publish my VSCode extension according to the steps described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/publish-extension

But it fails with the following error:
Error: Error parsing manifest file: not a valid JSON file.

[image: parsing error]

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Probably your manifest is an invalid JSON file, I'd say. We might be able to say more if you would dare to add it to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `package.json` file is valid JSON.

Open it in VS Code and you will see any syntax errors as decorations in the editor.

Comment: Got it solved. It turned out I added some comments to the package.json which is not allowed.